# Xcode, no debug symbols for certain subclass

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging, gdb, debug-symbols

I'm using Xcode 3.2.3 and iPhone SDK

So I'm trying to debug a UIView subclass, I hit a breakpoint in an overridden method and I can't see any symbols in either the GUI or gdb, just globals and registers.

This is what I see:

```
(gdb) po self
No symbol "self" in current context.
```

Yet when I set a breakpoint in a UIViewController subclass, all the symbols are there:

```
(gdb) po self
<MyViewController: 0x5c18ae0>
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
```

Some things I've tried:

- clean all/rebuild
- restart Xcode
- change between debug and release
- config these options in Project
  settings:

  - GCC_DEBUGGING_SYMBOLS = All
  - Symbols DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT = DWARF, DWARF w/ dSYM File
  - BUILD_VARIANTS = normal, debug
- threatening Xcode by swearing at it and typing
  `rm -rf /Developer` into a root bash prompt

Please help, my fingers are bleeding from debugging with NSLog

Answer (score 4):

I experience this bug often. My workaround is typing the bt command on the gdb console, it then automagically sorts itself out and starts recognizing symbols in the current context.

Comment: This answer worked immediately for me in XCode 8. Fantastic answer!

Answer (score 3):

So changing from *Debug* to *Release* did the trick and I have all my debug symbols.

I think it's just a bug in the 4.0 SDK.

Comment: This worked for me as well. Not intuitive at all. Changing to release build so you can get at symbols...

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, tried to repro this in 3.2.3 and SDK4 Final with no success -- able to debug UIView subclass as expected.  Is this occurring using one of the beta releases?

Answer (score 0):

Happening to me, on a non-beta release.  I just noticed that it only occurs when calling a class-defined method, ie  (+) not (-)

I wouldn't mind not having a "self" pointer, but it also seems to wipe out all local variable displays in the debugger, and that is just wrong.

Answer (score 0):

MTS' method worked for me. Changing from debug to release fixes this issue. How strange. I can disprove software evolved's theory, as I experience the error inside an instance method.

Answer (score 0):

in gdb type **bt**.

If you see **self=<value temporarily unavailable, due to optimizations>** anywhere it's because xcode has been set to be optimized.

Go to the build settings and type **optimization**.

If optimization level for either debug or release is set to **Fastest** that's causing your issue.

Release should be left at fastest so your code run well when building for distribution. It's better to change your Build Configuration in Scheme.

opt+click the Run button. On the left click Run YourAppsName.app, then Info and select **debug**.